# Internet Explorer 7 menu wrapping

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have an issue with IE6&7 that I cannot debug.

I have a menu which displays fine in chrome, firefox, safari and IE8&9 but in IE6&7 the menu wraps at about the half way mark.

see here:- http://dublan.prodealerauto.com/

The top right menu wraps in IE6&7.

I've tried reducing width, padding, margin but no cigar...
What is forcing the wrap?

Comment: Why you cannot debug? use the Firebug Lite to debug: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: because I can't find the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you'll have to specify width to the .mainnav class since you are using float:right.

Comment: if that is the case, why does it only wrap after the 4th element - wouldn't it wrap after every list element? I'll give it a try anyway

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed width to your menu.